# Youtube jquery get video page html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, youtube

Hi I just wants to simply get a url from youtube and represent the html content..
My code looks like this now:

```
$.ajax({url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID",
                type: 'get',
                dataType:'jsonp',
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function(data,text,xhqr){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

And the result is:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rr5EyyhSU_k&callback=jQuery110209012887296266854_1387530192875&_=1387530192876". jquery.js:8516 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

And i got no data... Can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
    $.ajax({             
      url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/ public/yql',                 
      data: {q: "select * from json where url ='http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http:// www.youtube.com/watch? v=wbp-3BJWsU8&format=json'",format: "json" },  
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (data) {  
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      },             
      error: function (result) {
             alert("Sorry no data found.");
      }         
    });
```

Comment: I need the video's page content in html and not the embed url (http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=)

Comment: what you mean by " the video's page content in html " ?

Comment: for example this url's http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1JPKLa-Ofc content (it's an html content)

Comment: Then remove this(http://www.youtube.com/oembed?) in my answer and try. hope it will work